# Magento 1.9 - Customize the "Check / Money Order" Order Status from Pending to Complete

Tags: magento, customization, magento-1.9, payment-method

I've a Magento website that I'm using for some tests and I need to setup an easy payment method that can make me able to buy something without any risk to get real payment from random users but I also need to register this order with a "**complete**" status immediately (I've also another add-on that will export complete orders to an external platform but only if they're completed).

I was thinking to use the "**Check / Money Order**" but there is only one option configurable from "**System/Configuration/Payment Methods**" and it's the "**Pending**" status.

I'm quite new with Magento so, is there any easy method to change that status and register automatically the Order as Complete also if using the Payment method? If not, there is the possibility to enable another payment method without any Credit Cards, CC, Bank transfert,... option??

Thanks a lot!
Cheers
Francesco

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the links. Your question is very broad as is. We expect you to do the research, try a lot, and then when you're stuck ask a question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421is a good discussion that explains this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?